# How to keep JS script running across websites?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a javascript script which does the following:

1. Open a URL (base_url+random_string) (the URL is to a site that isn't mine)
2. Click a button
3. Goto 1

AFAIK JS runs in a browser, so is there a way to create a child instance of the browser which is handled by the JS script?

Right now, I think my script (located on my system) will not run after it opens the requested URL, as it is not present on that URL.

P.S. I'm running Chrome with `chromium-browser --disable-web-security` flag.

Comment: Can you not open the url in new window and then use window.top function? I think that may work.

Comment: Is the URL of the page you are opening one under your control?

Comment: @milan I just started with javascript for this particular program. I've figured out the random string, button click part. Could you please post this as an answer? (possibly with a small example)

Comment: @aug No, it is not my website.

Comment: Maybe this is because you placed the script to get loaded only when a particular condition is satisfied, try loading the script file in the head section

Comment: @AnukulSangwan, if the website you are trying to open is not yours, you will not be able to access it due to the limitations imposed by browser as it needs the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Though I have never done it, in theory you can use a web worker. As long as the page that started the works remain open all pages will be able to communicate with this worker via message events. Each page will have to run a script that handles communicate with the worker as the worker does not have direct access to the DOM on any page. Be careful with communication because any page from any domain can send a worker messages,

Comment: @Blindman67: The target page isn't his, so he can't access the document -- not from the UI thread, not from a web worker thread.

Comment: Then turn of security and open the pages in an Iframe, the iframe can be on top filling the page his page hidden but able to control navigation depending on what on the pages.

Comment: disabled Same Origin Policy. what next?

Comment: I have been running without security for ages. Never been a problem as I use another browser for the stuff that I don't want others to have unauthorized access to. Yet in all that time I have never had a threat appear. The benefits far outweigh any dangers in my view. But only for those that (think they) know what they are doing .

Comment: @Blindman67 Can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in standard client-side JavaScript, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Although you could open the window and keep a reference to it (via `window.open` or by putting it in an iframe), your code cannot then access the document *in* that window because the origins are different.

If you're doing this on your local machine, you can write yourself a Chrome extension or Firefox add-on that would be able to do it.

Comment: I can disable Same Origin Policy using `chromium-browser --disable-web-security`, but what do I do next?